# Python code not giving any output in PyCharm

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weIyH.jpg)I Am beginner trying to run below code but not getting any output:

```
def f():
    pass

def main(f=None):
    try:
        f()
        print("After the function call")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Divided by zero!")
    except:
        print("Exception")
        def f():
            print(1/0)
            main()
```

[image]

Comment: Your code does nothing but define two functions. You shouldn't expect any output.

Comment: from where did you call the `main()`?

Comment: For your reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html

Comment: Please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 1):

It is simple: you are not calling your own function:

```py
def f():
    pass

def main(f=None):
    try:
        f()
        print("After the function call")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Divided by zero!")
    except:
        print("Exception")
        def f():
            print(1/0)
            main()

main()
# Just call your function!
```